# Is there a way to see which php script is hogging the cpu?

Tags: php, performance, wordpress, cpu

I am running wordpress on nginx with spawn-fcgi on centos6. I have a lot of traffic coming through this server and the load on the cpu is often fine but sometimes the cpu gets maxed out at 99% for a long period of time and the `top` command says that the culprit is a few `php-cgi` processes. Is there any way for me to see what php script is causing my cpu to max out?

Comment: I had the same problem. You can check: http://serverfault.com/questions/321938/one-php5-cgi-process-uses-100-cpu

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`ps faxuewwww` solved the problem for me

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a job for ps -ef with grep and some filtering of your top display using the PID's you find. I am not sure what your processes look like BUT say you are looking for generic php processes.

You can do:

```
ps -ef | grep php
```

ps -ef will grab all of the processes in a decently detailed way and grep will filter the results to only return what you want. Next you crack open top with the -p flag for pid's and pass it a list of the pid's you found, comma seperated. For example:

```
top -p 123,456,789
```

That should let you monitor only the ones you want and you can reference the results of ps -ef | grep to match the pid's in top to the particular scripts in question. Hope this helps.

Comment: it works good to show you the php process and the script file but how do I know what php files are included in the main script?

Comment: I tried these: ***ps -ef --forest | grep php*** and ***ps aux --forest | grep php*** But not enough.